# Thousand separator in native JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

A while ago I think I've read somewhere that JavaScript at some point in the future will allow the following syntax, which introduces thousand separators:

```
const oneMillion = 1,000,000;
```

Now, today I was wondering if this is already supported by V8. However, I was not able to figure it out, because I don't know how to search the web for this feature. Since I don't remember the name of this feature, I tried looking for something such as *javascript thousand separator*, but this in the end only brought up tons of results that explain how to format a number as an appropriate string.

So, to cut my question short: **What is the name of this feature?**

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, that's it! If you turn your comment into an answer, I will happily accept it 

Comment: You don’t have to search it up to know if it’s supported. Open the developer console (F12) and give it a try: `1_000_000`.

Comment: Yes, but if you want to know in which version of Node.js support was added, it's helpful to know what to search for, instead of having to try each single version until you find the one you are looking for 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed feature is named [*"numeric separators"*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator) and is currently at stage 3 with TC39. It would only allow underscores, though, not commas (using commas for this would be ambiguous, given the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)):

```
const oneMillion = 1_000_000;
```

It's available from [V8 v7.5](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-75#numeric-separators) (which is part of Chrome 75, and Node.js 12.5).

Comment: "stage 3" does that mean it's on track to be introduced in ECMAScript 2019?